# If removeClass doesn't affect source code, what's the point?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of forms with this pattern:

```html
<form action="/go/special" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="something"/>
<input type="submit" class="general effect" value="click me"></form>
```

For each form that has `special` inside its action, I want to remove the `effect` class using this jQuery code:

```html
<script src="/js/colorbox.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    // find all forms that have "special" in the action, find their input, and add the class
    $('form[action*="special"] input[type="submit"]').removeClass('effect');
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

**`effect` class code:**

```
(jQuery, document, window), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".effect").click(function(t) {
        t.preventDefault();
        var e = $(this).closest("form");
        return $.colorbox({
            href: e.attr("action"),
            transition: "elastic",
            overlayClose: !1,
            maxWidth: $("html").hasClass("ie7") ? "45%" : "false",
            opacity: .8,
            data: {
                ago: e.find('input[name="a"]').val(),
            }
        }), !1
    })
```

Link to rest of Colorbox code:

https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/jquery.colorbox.js

The `effect` class is a [Colorbox](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox) plugin. if it exists, the form will be opened in the same window as modal window. If it doesn't, the form will be opened in a new tab.

The script does remove the `effect` class, but I can see it is being removed only when I inspect the element with my console.

The source-code however, is not being affected, and still shows that it contains the `effect` class.

Therefore, when I submit the form, it will use the colorbox plugin and open a modal window, instead of new tab.

Is there any point in using `removeClass` in the first place?

Is there any work-around?

Comment: What do you means by `source-code`?

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser, it modifies the DOM that's displayed. The source code is on the server, the browser can't change that.

Comment: The source code is what is initially loaded when the page load then the javascript is run and updates the DOM with your changes.

Comment: The point of using `removeClass` is to display things differently to the user. There's presumably CSS that applies to the class, so when you change the class the display will change.

Comment: Can you post that colorbox plugin code (or link to it)?

Comment: Sounds to me like a xy problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @weirdan added a link , and [here too](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/jquery.colorbox.js)

Comment: Isn't the colorbox plugin being loaded and binded before the actual submit? I mean, we are talking frontend javascript, it will definitely not change the source code. But, you can, verify on submit click or form submit if there's the class "effect" and if the class is found you initialize the colorbox plugin.

Comment: Question is all wrong...show how you are using colorbox and what behavior you expect

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith kill the caps please...we can all read without shouting. Ironic how you complain about other's noise while just adding more noise yourself

Comment: @charlietfl I edited my question to add the colorbox code, the behavior I expect is to open a new tab, instead of executing the colorbox code which means opening a modal layover window in the same tab.

Comment: @rockyraw so what is or isn't working as expected? Problem is not clear

Comment: @charlietfl see this [demo](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) click on Outside HTML (AJAX). You see the modal window which opens? this is what should happen when `effect` class is present. But Since I remove the class, I expect that the modal window will not load when clicking on submit. but it does keep loading (instead of opening the form in `_blank` new tab.

Comment: So you want behavior to change when you change that class attribute?

Comment: removing the class won't remove event handlers that were attached to an element using that class. It's the element itself that event occurs on, regardless of what changes have been made to that eleemnt Use `hasClass()` to see if it exists when event occurs

Comment: or remove the event listener using `off()`

Comment: @charlietfl What shall I do considering that I need colorbox to keep working for all other forms on same page for which I don't want to remove their `effect` class?

Comment: Here's a simple way to do it:  `$(document).on('click', ".effect",function(t) {...` just replace one line of your current click handler ...the first one

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't really get it, what is the part that will prevent any form with `special` from firing colorbox, but will allow the rest to do so? can you post it as answer?

Comment: @rockyraw You really have two problems here , one a computer science mis conception and an actual code issue . Your computer science problem is understanding that source code is read and processed into memory and changes to attributes on elements is not passed back to the file system but only in the ram of the page . I  know that is not exactly the way to explain it but it may suffice for your understanding . I hope you find an answer to your coding error as well .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as far as I can see is that you're preventing the default handling of the submit click action (which is to submit the form), but from your description it appears that you actually want the default action to happen. This is kind of confusing, but I'll take it that you want to change the behavior dynamically, depending on whether you have that class on the submit button or not.

This is a perfect case for [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Event delegation, in a sense, is a way to attach event handlers to elements that match a condition, now or in future, where the condition will be evaluated at the time of the event, not at the time of the attachment.

I will assume you want to attach your click handler to submit buttons having the `effect` class that are contained in any `form` tag, and that `form` tag already exists at the time of attachment (page load).

```
$(function() {
    $("form").on("click", "input[type='submit'].effect", function(t) {
        t.preventDefault();
        var e = $(this).closest("form");
        return $.colorbox({
            href: e.attr("action"),
            transition: "elastic",
            overlayClose: !1,
            maxWidth: $("html").hasClass("ie7") ? "45%" : "false",
            opacity: .8,
            data: {
                ago: e.find('input[name="a"]').val(),
            }
        }), !1
    });
});
```

What this does, under the hood:

1. Finds all `form` elements
2. Attaches `click` handler to every one of them, additionally adding `input[type='submit'].effect` selector to it
3. When click event bubbles up the DOM tree and reaches the `form` element, its source is checked to see if it matches that additional selector.
4. If it matches, the event handler is executed. It prevents the default action (submitting the form) and launches the colorbox instead.
5. If it doesn't match, it continues to bubble, eventually triggering the default action (form submit).

Comment: just need to tweak selector `submit.effect` but +1. That selector implies a tag `<submit>`

Comment: @charlietfl, ah, right, it should be something like `input[type=submit].effect`. I'll change the answer when I'll find the exact syntax supported by jQuery (soon)

Comment: that syntax is valid

Comment: @weirdan Great solution, thanks! Would you suggest a complete different way to approach this whole thing though?

Comment: @rockyraw, well, it appears you attach colorbox handler to `input.effect` elements at page load (dom ready), and removing the `.effect` class from some of the submits at roughly the same time. Couldn't you just omit the `.effect` class where you don't need it when you generate the html?

Comment: @weirdan This code is part of a template and will be used in various pages containing various forms. In each page I may change the default action path of a certain form (which is usually special) and in that case I don't colorbox. that's why I want the .effect class to change automatically, according to the path (special or not). I still didn't find a PHP solution that can do this in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> The script does remove the effect class, but I can see it is being removed only when I inspect the element with my console.
>
> The source-code however, is not being affected, and still shows that it contains the effect class.

The class is being removed. This is why you can see it removed when you inspect the element. I'm guessing when you say "source code" you are referring to the right click option "view source." When you view source you are looking at the raw code that the browser loaded before any javascript was ran. So any modifications that javascript makes to the page won't show up in the view source option. You will only see the changes in the browser's dev tools.

Comment: it is being removed in live html also ... problem is event is being bound before that